# How to show HTML data as normal string in Table in Repeater using asp.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, tags, asprepeater

I want to show HTML data as normal string in Table Data Cell. Following is my code and screenshot of result.

ASPX

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMainTable" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td><%# Eval("FieldValue").ToString()%></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

CS

```
private void addListData()
{
    List<TableClass> listTableAction = new List<TableClass>();
    listTableAction.Add(new TableClass(){ FieldValue = "<b>TestBold</b>"});
    listTableAction.Add(new TableClass(){ FieldValue = "test"});
    rptMainTable.DataSource = listTableAction;
    rptMainTable.DataBind();
}
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `HtmlEncode`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMainTable" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td><%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("FieldValue").ToString()) %></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

That will display the string as `<b>TestBold</b>`